# Vlocity Data Raptor - CONCAT Function Issue

Tags: formula, omnistudio, vlocity

I'm trying to concatenate values extracted from a JSON using a Data Raptor Transform formula, the JSON file looks like this with the exception that it has hundreds of data values

```json
{
  "Info": [
    {
      "Name": "Mary Baker",
      "Email": "mbaker@example.com",
      "Phone": "415-555-3331"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Joe Baker",
      "Email": "jbaker@example.com",
      "Phone": "415-555-3332"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Russell Baker",
      "Email": "rbaker@example.com",
      "Phone": "415-555-3333"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the formula I'm using is `CONCAT("The phone number for ", %Info:Name% , "is " , %Info:Phone%)`, however, when I try to run it I get this

```json
The phone number for Mary BakerJoe BakerRussell Baker is 415-555-3331415-555-3332415-555-3333
```

The formula is merging all values instead of returning it line by line.

I've read the function documentation but it seems to be in the same format.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you've used is correct. I was able to achieve the expected concatenated output by mapping the formula output to a new key "Result" in the same Info list. Please refer the following screenshots :

[image]

[image]

[image]